# Is there an English manual for the geometry package?

Tags: geometry, documentation, texdoc

I use `texdoc` to get package manuals. For the `geometry` package I have tried:

```
`texdoc geometry` which returned `geometry-de.pdf`

`texdoc geometry-en` which returned `geometry-de.pdf`

`texdoc geometry-eng` which found nothing.
```

Comment: There definitely is: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf I'm on a MikTeX system where `texdoc` does not quite work the same as on TeX Live, so I can't tell you the `texdoc` incantation, though. I would try `texdoc --list geometry`, maybe that gives you several options, one of which hopefully is `geometry.pdf`

Comment: I'm on TeXLive on a Mac, and `texdoc geometry` gives me the english manual.

Comment: Peter, exactly which texlive version are you using? The first one you list seems wrong.

Comment: @moewe do you have minute for me in the chat?

Comment: `texdoc geometry.pdf` should give the English manual, `texdoc -l geometry` lists all different options

Comment: @daleif I have `texlive/2021`

Comment: @cgnieder Thank you. `texdoc geometry.pdf` produced an English version of the manual. Do you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is both a German and English documentation on `geometry` as can be seen on https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

Sometimes `texdoc <pkgname>` doesn't lead to the expected document.

> […] the collected filenames are given numeric scores by using some
> heuristics. For example, a filename `⟨keyword⟩.pdf` is good, and
> thus gets a high score. A name `⟨keyword⟩-⟨lang⟩.pdf` is also good and
> gets a higher score if the `⟨lang⟩` is the preferred language code in
> your configuration. […] Finally, a file with the highest score is
> opened with a viewer, or the list of results is shown, depending on
> the current mode.

In such cases `texdoc -l <pkgname>` can be helpful. In the case of `geometry` this (on my computer) leads to:

```
clemens@earth:~> texdoc -l geometry
 1 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry-de.pdf
   = [de] Package documentation (German)
 2 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf
   = [en] Package documentation (English)
 3 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lapdf/geometry.pdf
 4 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/metapost/mp3d/tugboat-geometry-space.pdf
   = [en] Paper on geometry, for TUGboat
 5 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/README.md
   = Package Readme
 6 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/changes.txt
 7 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/luatex/luatexja/lltjp-geometry.pdf
Enter number of file to view, RET to view 1, anything else to skip:
```

and shows seven different documents related to the `geometry` keyword, not all related to the `geometry` package

The second in the list above is the English package documentation. Calling the document by its full name with texdoc directly opens it:

```
texdoc geometry.pdf
```

For more on `texdoc` calling

```
texdoc --help
```

for the list of available options or

```
texdoc texdoc
```

for the documentation of `texdoc` itself can be helpful.